# Need to combine variables and format accordingly

Tags: objective-c

I have these varibles:

```
place.address
place.city
place.state
place.zip
```

(where each of those would equal what you'd expect ex. place.address = 123 main st. and place.city = Chicago)

How do I set it up so it would be combined and formated correctly similar to a letter.

```
123 main st.
Chicago, IL 60609
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `[Place formatAddress]` (this assumes `place` is an instance of a class called `Place`):

```
- (NSString *)formatAddress
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@, %@ %@",
        self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zip];
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Im new to objective-c and seems I was over thinking things, Thanks for your help!